# How to register OAuth2 clients from a persistent database in Spring Authorization Server?

Tags: spring-security, spring-oauth2, spring-authorization-server, spring-autoconfiguration

I'm using Spring Authorization Server for controlling access to services/resources and I have a list of client registrations configured in the application properties. I understand that the application properties are persisted in memory and will require redeployment if the properties are changed. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to make client registrations persisted on a database and be able to add new clients without causing downtime.

I'm aware this is something to do with [ClientRegistrationRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.12.RELEASE/reference/html/oauth2.html#oauth2login-register-clientregistrationrepository-bean)  but this was written for Spring Security 5 and now that we have a dedicated battery project (Spring Authorization Server) as a part of Spring Security 6, I would like to know if there is a better way to persist in a database for multiple client registrations and be able to dynamically add new clients without issuing any downtime. Thanks

Comment: you can use the `JdbcRegisteredClientRepository` as mentioned here in the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/core-model-components.html#registered-client-repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you can use `JdbcRegisteredClientRepository` (see [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/core-model-components.html#registered-client-repository)). Simply register it as a bean using the provided schema (see table definition mentioned in [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/client/JdbcRegisteredClientRepository.html)), and your persisted clients are available without downtime.

Also see the [sample config](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/main/samples/demo-authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.java) which [demonstrates this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/a04b336a0cdc70279d3de4415685776e99f1581b/samples/demo-authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.java#L132-L166).